# How to pass multiple images array using form data in Retrofit 2 kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin, multipartform-data, form-data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHdE2.png)

How to pass multiple images array using form data in Retrofit 2 kotlin

Comment: please paste the code here instead of screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your actual code here, instead of uploading it as an image. It is much easier for us to provide some help.

To help you with your question.
You are currently building and overwriting `requestBody` each time it loops inside the for loop. To avoid that, only the `addFormDataPart()` method should be inside the for loop.

If you would like you can also use `forEachIndexed()` to replace the for loop.

```
val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

galleryListArray.forEachIndexed { index, image ->
    requestBody.addFormDataPart("attachment[${index}]", image.toString())
}

requestBody.build()
```

Comment: how to set this index can you please explain? and what is that image?

Comment: I edited the answer. It seems I misplaced the arrow `->` when typing the answer. `index` and `image` are just parameter names, you can name them however you like https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each-indexed.html

Comment: To read more, you could also check out https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html